# differences in CSS when running at localhost against remote

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, css

I'm using Internet Explorer 8 in Windows 7 Professional, like all my developer team (Visual Studiou 2010 Premium). But, in three Internet Explorer 8, I have a difference in the CSS when running at localhost mode, and in remote mode (when the application is in the server). In Localhost mode, everything works correctly, but when I access the same application at the server, I can note some differences in CSS, some controls aren't in correct place, and we can see that just with three developers of our team, and all of us use the same configuration.

The application at the server is updated.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

IE is running in different compatibility modes then for each of you. Its a pain. Check out: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956197

Comment: But I use Internet Explorer 8, and the application works correctally. So I install the Internet Explorer 9, and I saw the problem with the CSS, some controls out of the correct place. So I turn to install the Internet Explorer 8, and now the controls is also out of place.

Comment: compare the zones and conmpatibility view settings  (tools-compatibility view) try running all sites in compatibility view and see if it makes a difference, and then undo it. If it changes - theres your issue.

Comment: Also - are your css files .css files or are you using aspx files as css files? If so you'll need to set the content type on those to be text/css - but I feel confident its your compat. view settings as I've seen this _exact_ issue before.

Comment: well, about "compare the zones and compatibility view settings" I try it right now, and the same error occurs. The CSS files are .css files.

Comment: that doesnt really tell me anything about what you tried or what you checked. See this for what Im talking about: http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/12/pages-in-ie-render-differently-when-served-through-the-asp-net-development-server-and-production-server.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Possibly an old version of the CSS is cached locally? CTRL+F5 or empty local cache might help.

Comment: Is empty now, but still the same results. This happens only with Internet Explorer 8 and 9.

Comment: ok, use the web dev tools to verify the linked CSS file. Also, you may want to put a version comment in as well for confirmation.

Comment: I can simulate the same error that occurs with three developers. Is just in Internet Explorer 9, in developer tools, simulate the Internet Explorer 7, so the CSS problem occurs.

Answer (score -1):

CSS is purely client-side. If you're getting different effects between local and remote, when using the identical browser running on the identical computer, then it means you're using different .css files and/or have different CSS in the page. You may *think* they're the same, but clearly, they are not.

Comment: But I use Internet Explorer 8, and the application works correctally. So I install the Internet Explorer 9, and I saw the problem with the CSS, some controls out of the correct place. So I turn to install the Internet Explorer 8, and now the controls is also out of place.

Comment: You need to narrow down this problem. Is there any computer where you can use the same version of the same browser and get different results based on whether your site is local or remote? In other words, try to find which change makes a difference and which changes do not.

Comment: John IE displays differences based on compat. mode which can be affected by zones. I've been nailed by this same issue before with the exact same css files : )

Comment: @Adam: note the question I asked him. One browser, one client computer, two different servers: does that cause different layout. If it doesn't, then maybe same browser, different clients, same server will cause a difference. It's necessary to keep everything constant except for one change, and keep varying what is constant and what is different until the problem appears.

Comment: we use the same configuration. (Machines, Softwares, etc). But in localhost, in Internet Explorer 8, it's okay. But the same Internet Explorer 8, when we run the application at the server, we can see that some controls are different.

Comment: @Lucas: then you'll need to compare what gets sent to the browser in the two cases. Maybe do "View Source" in both cases, save the HTML to files, then compare the files. If they're the same, then you'll have to do the same thing with the .css files that get sent to the browser; or use F12 and explore the differences in the CSS properties for the elements which differ. The only way for the problem to be server-specific is if the files on the server are different.

Comment: @John - yes - that can cause a different layout because the IE compat view may be different between zones (local) and remote. I've seen it render differently locally and fine against a server - its IEs silly 'I think I know better' setting, although its not actually labeled that : )  see this: http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/12/pages-in-ie-render-differently-when-served-through-the-asp-net-development-server-and-production-server.aspx

Comment: @Adam: O.M.G., I did _not_ know that. I don't believe I ever heard of any browser feature where rendering would be affected by zone.

Comment: its an awesome 'feature' , eh? : )

Comment: Never underestimate the creativity of Internet Explorer!